# How to Create Access DB on the fly from contents of MySQL database and save Locally

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

I have a remote MySQL database for my company's inventory.  The inventory database is the master database for all of the locations we subcontract equipment for.  Each property has its own inventory, and for quarterly inventory each location needs to take a laptop and a scanner, and scan their inventory, then sync it to the master database.

The problem is that internet access isn't readily available in all locations, so I need to copy the database to a local file.  Concurrency isn't an issue because only one client will ever be connected to the database simultaneously, and each location's database is relatively small, composed of basically <1000 rows of 7 columns.

I have gotten as far as creating an Access file on the HD, but I can't really divine from MSDN how to create a file with a specific schema or how to insert the relevant data from my SELECT statement into said database.  I'd been looking onto creating a table adapter on the fly and using .NET's built in methods to do the data transfer, but I still can't find how to create an MS Access file with a specific schema programatically. If anyone has encountered such a problem before, I'd appreciate any insight that could be offered.  I basically need to copy the results of a SELECT statement into an MS Access database which I will store locally.  All the other code I've got in place.

I'm presently using a rather unwieldy query and foreach loop to do my dirty work, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution, perhaps using a data source created on the fly.

```
ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();

        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="+ fileName + ";" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";" + "User Id=admin;Password=;";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);

        con.Open();

        //create command to generate database schema
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE items (
            [category] VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
            [manufacturer] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
            [model] VARCHAR(32),
            [description] TEXT NOT NULL,
            [serial_number] VARCHAR(64),
            [barcode] VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            [property] VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
            [present] TINYINT
        )";

        command.Connection = con;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand();
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO items([category],[manufacturer],[model],[description],[serial_number],[barcode],[property],[present]) VALUES (@cat,@man,@mod,@desc,@ser,@bar,@prop,@pres)";
        cmdInsert.Connection = con;

        foreach (DataRow row in itemsTableAdapter1.GetData())
        {
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat",row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@man", row.ItemArray[1].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mod", row.ItemArray[2].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", row.ItemArray[3].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser", row.ItemArray[4].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", row.ItemArray[5].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prop", row.ItemArray[6].ToString());
            cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pres", row.ItemArray[7]);
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        con.Close();
        cat = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this previously but found that in order to create a new AccessDB I actually had to copy an existing database with all the tables etc that I required.

Would you be able to use [sqlite?](http://www.sqlite.org/)  It is tiny, stable and libraries are available for most languages.  You will be able to create whatever structure you like  on the client machine.

Comment: People have to be able to use this off site without my help.  I can't set up sqlite on every computer that they're going to be using.  The code above works.  It creates an Access Database, stores the file locally, then opens it up and copies all the relevant data over from the remote mySQL server.  I was just hoping that there was a cleaner way involving .NET's data structures.

Comment: As for your troubles with Access, use the code above, it actually creates a database out of thin air and stores it on the local hard drive.

Comment: @spuy767 I still think Toby's point is valid. It would be quicker and easier to copy an already created but empty database to the local machine and then populate the tables, or even populate and then copy. Access is file based so treat it as a file. However, I agree that sqlite is not the answer.